# Moving an answer on old but hot topics?

Tags: discussion

I posted an answer on this subject:

[How to create a very big photo (like for a billboard)](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/45833/how-to-create-a-very-big-photo-like-for-a-billboard/45844#45844)

It has already some votes, but there is a "hot topic"

[What resolution should a large format artwork for print be?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/487/what-resolution-should-a-large-format-artwork-for-print-be)

It is more likely that in the future people will look into that second post than the first one.

As I think my answer aports new light on the subject, What could be a curse of action? Can the answer be moved?, Copied, Re writed in new terms and more complete to be not an exact duplicate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want you can post your answer on the other question and delete it from the question marked as a duplicate.

Depending on someones searh criteria similar questions or questions marked as duplicate will appear on the right side as related questions.

Its really up to you but as stated in your other meta question a mod would not remove your question because it is voted on.

So it would really be up to you.  You could move it and edit the answer to be a better fit for the other question.

If you've posted the answer and you cant delete that amswer due to insufficient rep feel free to flag for mod attention and we can assist.

Comment: Ok. But I supose that making a more elaborated and clear answer will be an option too, right?